# Am I being hacked? Why can't I change the firewall settings?

Tags: macos

I'm attaching a picture of my Privacy Settings and there is a screensharing and file sharing settings that I cannot modify. Can someone tell me if this is default, or if I got hacked. If so, **how can I disable these seemingly hard coded settings?**

[image]

I'm using High Sierra 10.13.6

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not any kind of sign that you've been "hacked".

If you enable anything in the Sharing prefs pane, then it will automatically enable the relevant service in the Firewall settings.
Disabling the service will remove the firewall setting.

It would be potentially highly confusing if you could switch on a service, then block it in the firewall.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. I don't remember enabling those sharing settings manually and I have no recolection of them being enabled last time I checked the Firewal settings. But now I disabled them, so I guess that will do it. If they somehow get re-enabled then should I worry?

Comment: Just restarted, no sharing settings were enabled again.

Comment: Cross that bridge if you come to it. Not remembering if you did it is not the same as not doing it - & hiding behind the sofa in case it ever 'just happens' again is a bit counter-productive;)